# Does Mac OS UUID depend on hard disk?

Tags: macos, uuid, hard-drive

I use this code to get UUID on Mac OS

```
NSString* getComputerId()
{   
    io_registry_entry_t ioRegistryRoot = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/");
    CFStringRef uuidCf = (CFStringRef) IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(ioRegistryRoot, CFSTR(kIOPlatformUUIDKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    IOObjectRelease(ioRegistryRoot);
    return (NSString*) uuidCf;
}
```

Does this UUID depend on hard disk? Will UUID change if users replace their hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

There's no mention of the HDD in the [CFUUID documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html)